# how to pass parameter in url Afnetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I want to know how to pass parameters to the query string using `AFNetworking`.

URL should be like `http://website.com/john/search?col=23,24&age=56-90&gender=m&add=rol`

```
 NSDictionary *params = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];

    [params setValue:@"23,24" forKey:@"col"];

    [params setValue:@"56-90" forKey:@"age"];

    [params setValue:@"m" forKey:@"gender"];

    [params setValue:@"rol" forKey:@"add"];


NSString * url = @"http://website.com/john/search";

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

        manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

        manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

        [manager GET:url parameters: params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

             NSLog(@"VALUES %@",responseObject);

        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

            failure(error);

        }];
```

Comment: AFN would do that for you, so don't bother

Comment: Can i print the URL to see if its correct ? And i dont get the intended results. So something is wrong.

Comment: You are doing it correctly, just receive your parameter like in PHP $_GET['key'];

Comment: I don't have control over the back end. So is there anything i could from my side.

Comment: your coding is correct , what the problem u faced